# inject div element between handlebars each

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

I want to place a div after fourth element of `#each`

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
{{#each names}}
  {{name}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

If there are no 4 elements then in last. How can I do achieve this?

Comment: Could you share your helpers as well so it's easier to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
{{#each names}}
  {{name}}
  {{#if fourth @index count}}
     <div></div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

js

```
Template.templateName.helpers(
   {
      count: function(){
           //if you are using iron router to return names
           return Router.current().data().names.find().count();
           // or you could get length from a reactive variable or session 
           // or if you are returning names as a helper, then set the length there
      },
      fourth: function(i, count){
         i = i+1;
         return i%4===0 || count===i;
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: Thanks .. Works fine

Comment: On deletion of each 'name' above the inserted div, I want the 'name' element  below inserted div to move up. How can I do this?

Comment: How are you deleting them? If u r removing them from the collection, and thus the cursor, I would imagine Blaze would just reindex them. So it should automatically fix up ur issue.

Comment: I guess deleting the item from client collection won't make the {{#each}} to re-render. So this will just move the inserted div above(it will be after 3rd 'name' now).So do I have to use an autorun and use jquery methods to move it back after 4th 'name'?

Comment: Is the collection only on the client? It will probably rerender even so. Though you should write a method call and delete the document on the server, as well as deny any delete/update/insert requests on the client side for security reasons.